# Can I use NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle without crashing on older devices?

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I don't have any device older than 4.1 to test on. I'm trying to test out pushing my notifications with the code below. It's mostly all taken from the [Notification documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). Would my code crash or does the NotificationCompat class handle all of this for me gracefully?

Under the "Handling Compatability" section it reads:

### Handling compatibility

> Not all notification features are available for a particular version,
>   even though the methods to set them are in the support library class
>   NotificationCompat.Builder. For example, action buttons, which depend
>   on expanded notifications, only appear on Android 4.1 and higher,
>   because expanded notifications themselves are only available on
>   Android 4.1 and higher.
>
> To ensure the best compatibility, create notifications with
>   NotificationCompat and its subclasses, particularly
>   NotificationCompat.Builder. In addition, follow this process when you
>   implement a notification:
>
> ...

So does this mean that if I use the NotificationCompat class it will handle all of the compatibility for me?

My code that I'm worried about (because it uses BigTextStyle):

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText(String.format("%s", message));
        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(mContext, ActivityMain.class);

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for
        // the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mContext);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Add max priority
        mBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
        // Add bigTextStyle
        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        bigTextStyle.bigText(String.format("%s", message));
        mBuilder.setStyle(bigTextStyle);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have nothing to worry about.

> Helper class for generating large-format notifications that include a lot of text.
>   If the platform does not provide large-format notifications, this method has no effect. The user will always see the normal notification view.

([NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html))

Comment: Aha. Can't believe I seemed to have looked all around the documentation except for the BigTextStyle class itself. I assume that something like setPriority() has no effect either (won't crash) even though it's only available to 4.1 and above?